# Is it possible to make Bootstrap 3 responsive tables scroll in a Motorola Droid Razr, with the onboard browser?

Tags: android, responsive-design, twitter-bootstrap-3

I could use some fresh ideas, please!

Title says it all, really: my test Droid Razr is not allowing me to scroll on Bootstrap responsive tables in its own on-board browser.

Presenting the content differently (e.g. non tabular, or changing the table layout) isn't an option for my client; is there a way to get the Razr to scroll the table?

Thanks!

PS: Bootstrap's own examples of responsive tables don't work in this handset/browser combo so I think this might be a non-starter...

Comment: I can't speak to the Droid Razr, but the Note 3's default browser works with http://jsfiddle.net/koala_dev/VwF6t/ (for scrolling horizontally).

That's one of the drawbacks with the default browsers on the various manufacturer handsets. They're rarely (never?) updated and tend to have suspect functionality.

Comment: you can hide some table column for mobile with `.hidden-xs`

Comment: Thanks Robert - the default browser seems to be a sticking point. That example seems to be the Bootstrap responsive table demo code, which doesn't work; so I think I'm stuck!

Comment: bboymaanu - unfortunately changing the presentation of the content - e.g. by hiding columns - is not allowed by my client.